# Is there a way to pass user authentication from a Wordpress site to ASP.NET api?

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, vue.js, authentication

I have an existing  Wordpress website using Woocommerce for the store and need to add a new form to one of the pages. The form is created in Vue and will be speaking to a backend API running on ASP.NET.

Is there a way to hijack the authentication and authorization provided by Wordpress by the backend API? The only solution I can see atm is to either have the user login again (this time to the endpoints going to ASP.NET (super inconvenient for the user)) or somehow when a user logs into the main site, have the PHP script send that to an additional backend endpoint maybe

The page itself is inaccessible without a user being logged in however, it does mean the endpoints are still open to the world without authentication to the ASP.NET api

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Develop an OAuth 2.0 system to enable the authentication to third party applications

Comment: @Jaquarh I'm doing this because I was basically given this WP website to add a new form that has a bit more logic than the original form. I have little experience with PHP and even less with WP. Are you suggesting to replace the current login method with an OAuth system? Also, we don't wanna allow any third party signins (google, facebook, github, etc...), just local accounts